# HTTP Status 404 with basic Spring 4 MVC Rest Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to follow a basic tutorial to get my application up and running, the one found here: http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-rest-service-example-using-restcontroller/

Currently I have the following classes:

AppConfig.java:

```
package com.cgi.miam.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.cgi.miam")
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

}
```

WebAppInitializer.java:

```
package com.cgi.miam.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class WebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/*" };
    }
}
```

MemberController.java:

```
package com.cgi.miam.controller;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MemberController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome() {// Welcome page, non-rest
        return "Welcome to RestTemplate Example.";
    }

    @GetMapping("/person/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity getCustomer(@PathVariable("id") Integer id) {

        return new ResponseEntity("test", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

And my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.cgi.miam</groupId>
    <artifactId>miamWebApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>miamWebApp Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-b01</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>SpringRest</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                        <warName>MemberInformation</warName>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

I've deployed it in Tomcat 9.0 within Eclipse and it starts succesfully. However, I always get a 404 not found if I go to http://localhost:8080/MemberInformation/ or http://localhost:8080/MemberInformation/person or http://localhost:8080/MemberInformation/person/2. It seems that all tutorials can start and fetch the information at this point, but here it doesn't seem to work. The 'MemberInformation' app seems to be deployed when I browse to http://localhost:8080/manager. Any tips?

Comment: Why `/MemberInformation/...`?

Comment: Did u deploy the WAR file in tomcat?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've updated my question with my pom.

Comment: @SathishJayapal I've updated my question with my pom.

Comment: @Joetjah Are you sure the context path of your application is MemberInformation what happens when you do
http://localhost:8080/person/2

Comment: @NickDiv Also a 404.

Comment: @Joetjah Can you open the Tomcat manager and see your application deployed there? Usually it would be http://localhost:8080/manager

Comment: @NickDiv I'm trying to figure this one out, since I've got it in Eclipse. I do use the Tomcat Installation though.

Comment: @NickDiv Got in. The app seems to be deployed. If I click on the name, it brings me to a 404 page. It is running, though.

Comment: You may want to quality your methods with `produces="plain/text"` to make sure they are the target of your browser requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my problem was in the way I deployed the webservice. The following part in the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
        <warName>MemberInformation</warName>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Caused the war file to deploy to that location, and even though the app was added to the Tomcat server within Eclipse, it didn't deploy. Solution was to either comment out this part of the pom, or transport the generated war file to the Tomcat Webapps folder.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that fact that `Spring` cannot find your `RestController`. In your `@Configuration`, please note how you need to specify the base package. Try this:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.cgi.miam") //will look into com.cgi.miam.controller as well
```

instead of..

```
@ComponentScan("com.cgi.miam")
```

Comment: I figured the same, since some other answers noted that you'd see something in the Tomcat logging on startup and I don't. However, changing it according to your suggestion unfortunately didn't work.

Comment: What do you see as a Response in your Network tab of your Browser?

Comment: It's red, with 404 Not Found as response to /MemberInformation/